# What causes log output to the active console?

Tags: logs, tty, console, manjaro, systemd-journald

I'm running Manjaro ARM 64bit on a Raspberry Pi (more specific question [there](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/99800/3763)), but this question is more general: Which settings might cause log output to be always displayed on the active console? I already tried:

- setting `console=/dev/tty1` instead of `tty0` in `cmdline` in the hopes of fixing the output to tty1 instead of the currently active one
- settings in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`:

  - `TTYPath=/dev/tty1` instead of the implicit default `/dev/console`
  - `MaxLevelConsole=err` (just for testing, I would like to still see info on tty1)
  - `ForwardToWall=no` (just in case...)

To no avail, I still get log output equivalent to that of `dmesg --follow` on whatever tty I'm currently on. What else could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: What type of log output?

Comment: @Kusalananda Uhm, now that you mention it... It's actually identical to the output of `dmesg`, e.g. `[36300.723412] bcm2835-power bcm2835-power: Timeout waiting for grafx power OK` (which btw seems to indicate I shouldn't use the USB switcher I use without a power supply...)